# nbsphinx - Align figure to center

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx

I include images in in a markdown cell using the command: `![logo](images/jupyter.png)`. In jupyter notebook it is rendered aligned on center. However, when i compile the html with sphinx, using nbsphinx extension, the images align on left. Is there a command to centralize them? I read all the nbsphinx documentation and did not find anything.